# Builtin "less" from stdlib "less"

Tags: agda

I would like to convert the standard library "less" into the builtin (boolean) one.

Here is what I have so far:

```
open import Agda.Builtin.Equality
open import Agda.Builtin.Bool
open import Agda.Builtin.Nat using (_<_)
open import Relation.Nullary using (Dec;yes;no)
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ;zero;suc;_<?_;z≤n;s≤s)

convert : ∀{a b p} → (a <? b) ≡ yes p → (a < b) ≡ true
convert {_} {zero} ()
convert {zero} {suc _} _ = refl
convert {suc a} {suc b} {Data.Nat.s≤s p} eq = 
  convert {a} {b} {p} ?
```

The last question mark is the question.

**Edit**: as suggested by gallais, it's easier to prove using an auxiliary lemma. The following code does the job:

```
lemma : ∀ {a b} → a Data.Nat.< b → (a < b) ≡ true
lemma {a} {zero} ()
lemma {zero} {suc b} eq = refl
lemma {suc a} {suc b} (s≤s eq) = lemma eq

convert : ∀{a b p} → (a <? b) ≡ yes p → (a < b) ≡ true
convert {_} {zero} ()
convert {zero} {suc _} _ = refl
convert {suc a} {suc b} {Data.Nat.s≤s p} eq = lemma p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to prove a more general lemma:

```
lemma : ∀ {a b} → a Data.Nat.< b → (a < b) ≡ true
```

And then conclude by:

```
lemma : ∀ {a b p} → (a <? b) ≡ yes p → (a < b) ≡ true
lemma {p = p} eq = convert p
```